# Openness of strong irreducibility

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated group.
A linear representation of $\Gamma$ is *irreducible* if it does not preserve a proper subspace, and *strongly irreducible* if it does not preserve a finite union of proper subspaces.

It is known that the set of irreducible representations is Zariski open in the variety of representations $ \mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, SL(n,\mathbb{C}))$ (see [Sikora "Character varieties"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2589.pdf), prop. 27).

Is the set of strongly irreducible representations open in $ \mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, SL(n,\mathbb{C}))$, for either the Zariski or the classical topology ?